# Eliminar tabla de usuario dtproperties SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

¿Existe alguna consecuencia de eliminar la tabla de usuario `dtproperties` de SQL Server?, Estoy Filtrando los permisos del Role `Public` y verificando que este Role no tenga permisos DML y DDL diferentes a los Default que apunten a tablas de usuario ya que de lo contrario todos los usuarios tendrian esos permisos sobre esa tabla y tendria un fallo de seguridad.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: `dtproperties` si mal no recuerdo era la tabla dónde se salvaban los diagramas de base de datos, en teoría más que perder estos, no habría otro problema.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho creo que sería bueno que tu comentario lo incluyas como respuesta. Además, si lo elimina podría volver a generarla cuando construya un diagrama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tabla `dtproperties`, junto con varios objetos `dt_*` están asociados con la creación de diagramas tipo DER desde el SQL Enterprise al menos hasta la versión de SQL 2000. Si no nos interesa mantener estos diagramas, podemos hacer un `DROP` de la tabla sin mayor consecuencia que la pérdida de estos diagramas.